# Apply Center Manifold Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I am given the system

$x' = -x +y +x^2 +ax^3$

$y' = x -y +ax^2 +bxy +y^3$.

I have to determine the stability of the origin. After doing the linearisation I get the eigenvalues

$λ_1 = 0$ and $λ_2 =-2$.

According to my notes, in order to apply the Center Manifold Theorem, the system must be in the following form:

$x' = f(x,y)$

$y' = -y + g(x,y)$.

If the linear part of the system is not like the form shown before then I can use a transformation and bring it in the desired form. Which transformation should I use? Or am I missing something here?

Thanks for your effort !

Answer (score 2):

> According to my notes, in order to apply the Center Manifold Theorem, the system must be in the following form:
> $x' = f(x,y)
> \quad$ $y' = -y + g(x,y)$.

Not exactly. The system must have the form
$$
y'= A_1 y+f(y,z),\qquad z'= A_2z +g(y,z),
$$
where all eigenvalues of $A_1$ have zero real parts and all  eigenvalues of $A_2$ have negative real parts. In the problem under consideration, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are real numbers, therefore, $A_1=0$, $A_2<0$.

The linearization matrix is
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{array}\right).
$$
The matrix whose columns are eigenvectiors of $A$ is
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{array}\right),
$$
thus,
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1\\
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}z_1\\z_1\end{array}\right),
$$
i.e.
$$
x=z_1+z_2,\qquad y=z_1-z_2
$$
or
$$
z_1=\frac12(x+y),\qquad z_2=\frac12(x-y).
$$
Indeed,
$$
z_1'= \frac12( x'+ y')=
\frac12( -x +y +x^2 +ax^3+x -y +ax^2 +bxy +y^3)
$$
$$
=\frac12( (z_1+z_2)^2 +a(z_1+z_2)^3 +a(z_1+z_2)^2 +b(z_1+z_2)(z_1-z_2) +(z_1-z_2)^3)
$$
$$
=f(z_1,z_2);
$$
$$
z_2'= \frac12( x'- y')=
\frac12(-x +y +x^2 +ax^3-x +y -ax^2 -bxy -y^3)
$$
$$
=-x-y+\frac12((z_1+z_2)^2 +a(z_1+z_2)^3-a(z_1+z_2)^2 -b(z_1+z_2)(z_1-z_2) -(z_1-z_2)^3)
$$
$$
=-2z_2+g(z_1,z_2).
$$

Comment: Yes, that is true thanks a lot. I managed to solve it.